# Deployment with customer handler on Google Cloud Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai, torchserve

I'm trying to deploy a TorchServe instance on Google Vertex AI platform but as per their documentation (https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements#response_requirements), it requires the responses to be of the following shape:

```json
{
  "predictions": PREDICTIONS
}
```

Where **PREDICTIONS** is an array of JSON values representing the predictions that your container has generated.

Unfortunately, when I try to return such a shape in the `postprocess()` method of my custom handler, as such:

```py
def postprocess(self, data):
    return {
        "predictions": data
    }
```

TorchServe returns:

```json
{
  "code": 503,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "Invalid model predict output"
}
```

Please note that `data` is a list of lists, for example: [[1, 2, 1], [2, 3, 3]]. (Basically, I am generating embeddings from sentences)

Now if I simply return `data` (and not a Python dictionary), it works with TorchServe but when I deploy the container on Vertex AI, it returns the following error:  `ModelNotFoundException`. I assumed Vertex AI throws this error since the return shape does not match what's expected (c.f. documentation).

Did anybody successfully manage to deploy a TorchServe instance with custom handler on Vertex AI?

Comment: What do you mean : `data` is a list of lists? can you add example?

Comment: I just added an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, making sure that the TorchServe processes correctly the input dictionary (instances) solved the issue. It seems like what's on the [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/pytorch-google-cloud-how-deploy-pytorch-models-vertex-ai) did not work for me.